# How do you capture the text that follows a Regex match in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on an assignment in which I need to search through a web site and extract conversion rates.

If I was able to simply match the rates this would be simple to capture and extract, but I need to be able to hit an update button and have the program search for the updated conversion rates, so I am not able to simply hard code a match to search for.

**Is there a way in which I can match the text that precedes the rates and capture all text that follows the match?**

If there is a better way to do this I am also open to suggestions. I just need help to know **how to get the rates from the website when I do not know exactly what the rates will be.** I simply know the format of the rates and where the rates are located within the site.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String regex = "(?<=EUR'>)\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?(?=<)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(?);

while (match.find()) {   
  System.out.println("Found a match: " + match.group(1).toString());  
  System.out.println("Start position: " + match.start(1)); 
  System.out.println("End position: " + match.end(1)); 
}
```

I think i understand how to set up the pattern, but I am unsure as to what I should put for the match string if I only know what the beginning and end will be and not the end...

An example of what I would need to grab is the line below

```
<td class='rtRates'><a href='/graph/?from=USD&amp;to=EUR'>0.772000</a></td>
```

I need to grab the rate in this line, but it will constantly be changing

Comment: `(.*?)match-expression(.*?)`? (If this isn't what you want, maybe you should *clarify your post by giving examples*?)

Comment: Give some examples, how the rates look like. You can't possibly expect people to guess what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex to parse html, or a velociraptor will come and eat you. Use something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and query value of an `<a>` element that is inside a `<td>` with class `rtRates`.

Comment: Ha if I had the choice I wouldn't, but it is required to do so for this assignment...

Comment: @user1746105: you said you were open for suggestions :) anyways, I don't really get, what would be constantly changing in the line you give and what you need to match?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem is, because your expression is matching what you expect (I think). [See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32f5s).

If you want to be more flexible on what the part looks like between the tags, you can use this:

```
(?<=EUR'>)[^<]*
```

The `[^<]` is a negatied character class. It will match any character but `<`. Then you can also remove the lookahead assertion.

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32f5v)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use this?

```
EUR'>(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)<
```

The rate is captured in group #1, which is handy since you're already using `group(1)` to extract it. ;)  But seriously, there are no capturing groups in your regex, so calling `group(1)` on the Matcher result an exception.  What gives?

p.s. Notice that I changed your `\d*` to `\d+`.  Almost everyone who tries to match decimal numbers requires at least one digit after the decimal point.  If that's not the case here, go ahead and change it back.